# How to find and trim network interface id in powershell

Tags: powershell

My goal -
I want to find the interface number of a WiFi adapter and save it as a variable.

My attempt -

```
$index = netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces Wi-Fi | select-string -Pattern 'IfIndex'
$index -split ': '
$index[1]
```

This has gotten me a result but my noob instinct tells me there should be a much better way.

Comment: There's a cmdlet for that, [Get-Netadapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter?view=windowsserver2022-ps), try it instead of running `netsh`

Comment: I came to `Get-Netadapter -Name 'Wi-Fi' | Format-list -Property "ifIndex"`, resulted in `ifIndex : 2`. Do I need to `split` from here as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Powershell way is not to trim text, but to access object properties. Splitting strings is the way to go in CMD and *nix shells, since those are text-oriented. Powershell, however, is based on objects.

That being said, take a look at what properties there are (use `| get-member` to see those) in the CimInstance object that Get-NetAdapter returns. There's promising one, `ifIndex`:

```
$n = get-netadapter -name 'wi-fi'
$n.ifIndex
# output
2

# This also works, if you don't need the object:
(get-netadapter -name 'wi-fi').ifindex
# output
2
```